# Put and delete asks for authentication: MVC 5

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a simple Angular CRUD page here:http://www.centralreservations.org/. It is using MVC 5. The "Add new" works fine but "delete" and "edit" do not. I am prompted for a username and password. It isn't insufficent permissions on the database as the user is admin on the db.
On the error console on the browser it goes down on line 39 of "Emp.js" (http://centralreservations.org/Scripts/Emp.js).
This doesn't occur on localhost (edit, save and delete work fine) so I assume it is a hosting issue. I don't have access to IIS on the hosting server so I cannot change any of those settings. I have made several changes to web.config based on searches through past posts on this issue in stackoverflow but none have made a difference.
I would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I have got past that error but now I am getting an error 500 (Internal Server Error) upon a delete or edit.

Answer (score -1):

This problem was not caused by a coding error or missing code. It is an IIS issue that was resolved by moving the site to another server. Something in IIS 7.5 was not configured correctly. Once I moved the site to a different hosting server the error disappeared and "edit", "delete" and "add new" function perfectly. The new url is http://www.jgdoherty.org/